# Enable object of Form A using Form B

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, vb.net-2010

I am using this code to disable form [A] on my form.load event

```
Public Sub disableAll(ByVal root As Control)
    For Each root In root.Controls
        If Not root.Name.ToString = "cmdLogin" Then
            root.Enabled = False

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

using this code `disable(Me)`

and it works as intended.

The problem now is enabling it, I have this code to enable the objects inside form [A] using a command button in form [B]

```
   Public Sub enableAll(ByVal root As Control)
        For Each root In root.Controls
            If Not root.Name.ToString = "cmdLogin" Then
                root.Enabled = True
            Else
                root.Hide()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

I used `enableAll(frmMain)`,`enableAll(my.Forms.frmMain)`,`enableAll(WindowsApplication1.frmMain)`

But none of them work, I get no error message, and checking my `Intermediate Window` of my VB.Net 2010, `frmMain.Menustrip1.Enabled.Tostring` is set to True, while when I check it IN frmMain, the enabled property is set to false, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside FormB you need to use the instance of FormA (frmMain) that is currently displayed. You are using the default instance of frmMain (a very confusing and anti-oop design choiche made by MS).

You can retrieve the displayed instance of frmMain looking at Application.OpenForms collection

Before calling your *enableAll* run this code

```
Dim f = Application.OpenForms("frmMain")
If f IsNot Nothing then
    enableAll(f)
End If
```

Comment: There's no problem using the default instance in this situation if it was the default instance that was displayed in the first place. The problem arises when people create their own instances and then refer to the default instance elsewhere. Either use the default instance everywhere or nowhere. It's worth noting that the startup form for an application is the default instance of its type.